# Display Services of different servers in an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, server-side, status

I am trying to create a Monitoring dashboard on which I want to display all services and status of the services of a server in a ASP.NET C# page. The servers in this instances are on the same network. I would like to know how I could achieve this.

Currently I am able to display all the services which are running locally on my PC using the following code:

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
            Response.Write("List of running services : <BR>");
            foreach (ServiceController service in services)
            {
                Response.Write(string.Format(" Service Name: {0} , status {1} <BR>", service.ServiceName, service.Status.ToString()));
            }
```

Which works great but I need it to be specific to a server as well as specific services.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of C# code will allow the user to be able to display data in a datagrid and well as list the specific services on a server:

```
 string[] filterArr = { "WdiSystemHost", "WdNisSvc", "WebClient", "Wecsvc", "WEPHOSTSVC", "wercplsupport", "WerSvc", "WiaRpc" };
    //string MachineName1 = ".";
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(MachineName1);
    int k = 0;
    ServiceController[] newsers = new ServiceController[filterArr.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < filterArr.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < services.Length; i++)
        {
            if (services[i].ServiceName == filterArr[j])
            {
                selectedservices[k++] = services[i];
            }
        }
    }
    ServiceBoundGrid.DataSource = selectedservices;
    ServiceBoundGrid.DataBind();
```

The MachineName is currently commented out and set to default. The following piece of code is placed in the page load.

Witin the asp element, create a datagrid and insert the following boundcolums:

```
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Service name" SortExpression="ServiceName" DataField="ServiceName" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Display name" SortExpression="DisplayName" DataField="DisplayName" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" DataField="Status" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Can be stopped" SortExpression="CanStop" DataField="CanStop" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Can be Paused" SortExpression="CanPauseAndContinue" DataField="CanPauseAndContinue" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Can be Shutdowned" SortExpression="CanShutdown" DataField="CanShutdown" />
```

And that should be it.